# GCP Routes with GKE (IP alias enabled)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

We have a GKE cluster, with IP alias enabled, and I was expecting to hit Cluster-IP of a LoadBalancer type service, but I can't. It times out.

This is the scenario:

```
NAME                     TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)   
istio-ingressgateway     LoadBalancer   10.aa.bb.bb     35.aa.bb.cc   80:31380/TCP,443:31390/TCP,31400:31400/TCP,15011:31585/TCP,8060:31570/TCP,853:31552/TCP,15030:31762/TCP,15031:30685/TCP   52m
```

I have the service above that I want to access through the internal IP address (Cluster-IP), rather then the external one. I have IP alias enable in my project, so this is how looks like the VPC.

[image: VPC]

Since the VPC is aware of the IP addresses of the services, should it be able to route the requests to the cluster?

I tried without IP aliases, and setting a route manually that sends all the requests to 10.aa.bb.cc to a GKE node, then from there, it will reach the backend. That works, but it is not neat.

One thing I can't do is to set the LoadBalancer type service to be internal, since there are way many ports, and it is controlled by Istio, so I don't even want to touch it.

Any idea if this is an expected behavior or something is wrong?

Comment: From where are you trying to hit the internal ip of the service? form inside the gke cluster?

Comment: No. from the cluster would work. From a VM, in the project, in the same subnet.

Comment: Could you put the request you are using?

Comment: since the request is timing out, it is not hitting the internal load balancer, so the request doesn't really matter. Anyways, here it is: `curl -kI --resolve istio.example.com:80:10.aa.bb.cc http://istio.example.com`.

Comment: What ip is the istio.example.com pointing on? :)

Comment: To the internal IP address. that's in the curl command

Comment: I think IP alias is not affecting to the services. Only the pods. If you create a pod, and expose it, you can hit the pod directly, but not the service in front of it. I tested it, and that's the outcome. Although not documented, so could be a bug?

Comment: Could be something they want, the internal IP is only a liaison to the external one? If so you could create a new ClusterIP service to point the domain...

Answer (score 1):

Cluster IP of a service is not routable as explained at [1]

[1]https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips#restrictions